# htaccess rewrite to always redirect to a domain with prefix

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, base-url

I have this project I maintain which I run in XAMPP and by default the url is set to `http://localhost` and it will take the folder project name inside htdocs to access the content. For instance I have a folder called `test` so my base url should be `http://localhost/test`.

The issue I am facing now is, most of the link was written in something like `/profile.php` and it will redirect to `http://localhost/profile.php` instead of `http://localhost/test/profile.php`. I find it hard to do the testing and all when they redirect to the wrong url.

How do I write the htaccess so that it will always read `http://localhost/test` as the base url?

This is something I tried but since I still quite confuse with the rule so I was not able to achieve what I'm trying to do.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /test/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT :**

All php files are under `test` folder at 1st level so they can be accessed by browsing as `domain-url/any-file.php`. In my case it should be something like `http://localhost/test` as the domain name and `/profile.php` as first uri also referring to the file `profile.php`

Comment: Could you please do mention what sample urls you are hitting and by which files in backend they should be served?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I had it mentioned in my post. The link is written in html like `<a href="/profile.php">profile</a>` and I expect it to be redirected to `http://localhost/test/profile.php` but instead it redirect to `http://localhost/profile.php` where the word **test** is my folder name inside XAMPP htdocs. All urls were written with the start of `/` and when it gets clicked it will take `localhost` only as the domain name without `test`.

Comment: Ok, so where is your profile.php present actually? Is it inside test folder? Kindly do let know.

Comment: Yes it is. All files are under 1 level so they all can be accessed by `domain-name/file-name.php`